# UIBarButton unclickable in empty ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

i've created a tabBarController subclass  and linked 3 viewcontrollers to the TabBarController in the storyboard. In the 3 ViewControllers which is directly connected with the tabBarController the UIBarButtons wont react when i click. They wont show the log message and does not do the highlight color. It seems like the navigationBar interaction is disabled or something. When i present a view modally on top of one of the 3 ViewControllers i have no problem with interaction with a UIBarButton in the modally presented View. I'm wondering what could result in such? i've struggled with this for ours.

i don't know if this has anything to do with it aswell, but in the modally presented views this does also result in white statusBar textColor, but it does not change it in the 3 views connected to the TabBarController.

What could this issue be?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

i've simply manually added a UIBarButton in the storyboard and then connected this action.

```
-(IBAction)testAction :(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

You just take 3 Navigation Controller as your tab bar view controller rather than simply view controller.
And connect tab bar view controller with navigation controller.
On navigation controller there is one view controller, on that navigation bar put your bar button item and connect to IBAction Method.

Its works for me.

Comment: At the moment this is how it looks: http://i.imgur.com/qY553Tw.png. What are u suggesting?

Comment: Hi Federik Hagelund, You are right my concept is same as your image.

Comment: The issue was i was not hiding the navigationController in my Initial View